# Mongodb node js Rest api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a rest api setup using node js (6) and mongodb (3.0).  This is a react app that I ported over to a linux system.  No changes were made to the source code which was already working.  I'm starting my mongo db server using: `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

Here is my config file:

```
dbpath=/home/mo/Documents/dev/data/mongodb/

#bindIp: [127.0.0.1, X.X.X.X]

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

#logpath = /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

logappend = true
```

Here is my code for getting data from mongodb through the api (dataservice.js):

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var db = new mongodb.Db('expenses', new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, {}));

db.open(function (err, db_p) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
    db.collection('expenses', {strict:true}, function(err, collection) {
      console.log("Connected successfully to server and expenses collection");
      if (err) {
        console.log("The 'expenses' collection doesn't exist.");
        //populateDB();
      }
    });
});

exports.getCategories = function(req, res) {
    console.log('get distinct categories function entered');

    db.collection('expenses', function(err, collection) {
        collection.distinct("category",function(err, items) {
            console.log('search: distinct category');
            console.log(items);
            items.sort();
            res.json(items);
            // db.close();
        });
    });
}
```

Here is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');

const dataHandler = require('./db/dataService.js');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3001));

// Express only serves static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}

//allow cross origin access to avoid error received from using node-fetch, the problem does not exist when axios is used
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  //res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000'); //allow access from this port
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies


app.get('/api/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send([{name:'wine1'}, {name:'wine2'}]);
});

//test api: http://localhost:3001/api/categories

app.get('/api/categories', dataHandler.getCategories);
```

Just to test a call to `http://localhost:3001/api/test` works fine.  However, `http://localhost:3001/api/categories` doesn't return data.  I know the data is there.  I have some console.logs and the data service is being hit. What am I missing? I've moved this code around on different sytems and it has worked fine.

Comment: Any errors in the console ?. I don't see a place where you open the db connection.

Comment: So the api/categories returns a 200 but no data? and the console.log(items) logs the items?

Comment: I was getting a 404 error in the console. Console.log(items) returns [].

Comment: For anyone looking at this now here is a quick boilerplate example https://github.com/npinos/restful-express-mongodb-api

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  Many hours of wrangling just to find out there was a simple oversight.  I did learn a few things looking aroun though so it was worthwhile.  I did not pass in the right database name to my connection.  I was passing in the collection name.  So this line should say test not expenses:

```
var db = new mongodb.Db('expenses', new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, {}));
```

In a case like this do I just delete this or leave it?